# Styles inheritance stack for elements of a Graphics/GraphicsBox

Tags: graphics, notebooks, documentation, style, internals

You can skip to the bottom if you only care about the question.

**My original goal** was to control `FrameLabel` color from a notebook level  opposed to doing it explicitly in `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[{}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Xlabel", "Ylabel"}, LabelStyle -> Orange]
```

[image]

**Initial problem:** first of all it does not work

```
CurrentValue[ EvaluationNotebook[], {GraphicsBoxOptions, LabelStyle}] = Orange;
Graphics[{}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Xlabel", "Ylabel"}]
```

[image]

I won't go through all the details but among others I learned that `LabelStyle` is applied after `DefaultLabelStyle`, which was not working either. Then I was playing with `FrameStyle`, `DefaultFrameStyle`, `StyleData["Graphics"]`, `StyleData["GraphicsFrame"]`, to no avail.

`CurrentValue[ nb, {GraphicsBoxOptions, DefaultLabelStyle}]` is shielded by something and `DefaultFrameStyle` affects the frame color as well so it is not the same.

In addition to that I am aware of existance of `FrameTicksStyle` and friends.

**The final question is**, given all possible `GraphicsBox'` elements like ticks, ticks' labels, frame itself, frame label etc etc. Where and in what order do they inherit their style from, step by step or in form of a graph.

Is there any hope to try to set those styles on a notebook level (not on a stylesheet level nor expression level)?

Comment: I removed one example that was my mistake but the main question stands.